# If statement in SAS macro not always working

Tags: if-statement, sas, macros

I'm relatively new to SAS coding, and I'm trying to write this (see the whole code down below) macro that should evaluate performances (to_worse, to_better, recoveded, etc.) of several teams.

The problem is that this rule here:

```
        if team_&y.="&PROVIDER." and team_&i. eq "" and balance_&i. = 0 then do; regolarizzato = "regolarizzato"; end;
        else if team_&i. ne team_&y. and team_&y. eq "&PROVIDER." and team_&i. ne "" then do; to_worse="to_worse"; end;
        else if team_&i. = team_&y. and team_&y. eq "&PROVIDER." and balance_&y. > balance_&i. then do; to_better = "to_better"; end;
```

does not seem to be always properly wowking; it works most of the times, but not always, and I don't understand the reason why it's failing sometimes. Could any kindheardted fella please explain why this happens? Thank you so much in advance!

```
%let oggi = '07oct2022'd;


%let mese = %sysfunc (MONTH(&oggi.));
%IF &mese. < 10 %THEN %do; %let mese = 0&mese.; %end;
%let giorno = %sysfunc (DAY(&oggi.));
%let anno = %sysfunc(Year(&oggi.));
/*%IF &giorno. < 10 %THEN %do; %let giorno = 0&giorno.; %end;*/



%macro COSTI_1;

%let i = 0;
%DO i = 0 %TO &giorno.; 

    data COSTI_&i.;
    set data.initial_db_&mese.;
    format balance_&i. commax14.2;
    keep contract_number team_&i. balance_&i.;
    run;

%end;

%mend;
%COSTI_1;

data COSTI_db;
set COSTI_0;
run;


%macro COSTI_2;

%let i = 1;
%DO i = 1 %TO &giorno.;

    PROC SQL;
        CREATE TABLE COSTI_db AS
        SELECT         
             A.*,
             B.*
        FROM COSTI_db AS A LEFT JOIN COSTI_&i. AS B 
            ON (A.contract_number = B.contract_number);
        QUIT;
    run;
%end;

%mend;
%COSTI_2;


data COSTI_db;
set COSTI_db;
length team $ 20;
format team $CHAR30.;
team="altro";
run;



%MACRO COSTI_PROVIDER (PROVIDER);

data COSTI_db_&Provider.;
set COSTI_db;
run;
    
    %macro COSTI_A;
    
    %let i = 0;
    
    %DO i = 0 %TO &giorno.;
    
        data COSTI_db_&Provider.;
        set COSTI_db_&Provider.;
        
            if team_&i. = "&PROVIDER." then team = "&PROVIDER.";
            
        run;
        
    %end;   
    
    %mend;
    %COSTI_A;
    
    
    DATA COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
    set COSTI_db_&Provider. (where =(team="&PROVIDER."));
    
    length to_worse $ 20;
    format to_worse $CHAR30.;
    length to_better $ 20;
    format to_better $CHAR30.;
    length regolarizzato $ 20;
    format regolarizzato $CHAR30.;
    
    to_worse="no";
    to_better="no";
    regolarizzato="no";
    
    run;
    
    
    %macro to_worse;
    
    %let i = 1;
    %let y = %eval(&i.-1);
    
    %DO i = 1 %TO &giorno.;
    
        data COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
        set COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
            
            if team_&y.="&PROVIDER." and team_&i. eq "" and balance_&i. = 0 then do; regolarizzato = "regolarizzato"; end;
            else if team_&i. ne team_&y. and team_&y. eq "&PROVIDER." and team_&i. ne "" then do; to_worse="to_worse"; end;
            else if team_&i. = team_&y. and team_&y. eq "&PROVIDER." and balance_&y. > balance_&i. then do; to_better = "to_better"; end;
    
        run;
    
    %end;
    
    %mend;
    %to_worse;
    
    
    data COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
    set COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
    
    length esito_finale $ 20;
    format esito_finale $CHAR30.;
    format balance_affido commax12.2;
        
        if to_worse="to_worse" then esito_finale="to_worse";
        else if regolarizzato = "regolarizzato" then esito_finale="regolarizzato";
        else if to_better = "to_better" then esito_finale = "to_better";
        else if team_&giorno. = "&PROVIDER." then esito_finale = "in_gestione_oggi";
        
        if richiamo_o_repo = "&PROVIDER." and inflows < -1 then esito_finale = "richiamo";
        if richiamo_o_repo = "&PROVIDER." and to_normal > 1 then esito_finale = "repo";
    
        if team_0 = "&PROVIDER." then balance_affido = balance_0;
        else balance_affido = -1;
    
        drop INFLOWS TO_NORMAL RICHIAMO_O_REPO;
        
    run;
    
    
    %macro COSTI_B;
    
    %let i = 0;
    
    %DO i = 1 %TO &giorno.;
    
    data COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
    set COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
        
        if team_&i. = "&PROVIDER." and balance_affido = -1 then balance_affido=balance_&i.;
        
    run;
    %end;
    
    %mend;
    %COSTI_B;
    
    
    
    proc sql;
        create table RIEPILOGO_&PROVIDER.
        as select esito_finale, sum(balance_affido) as somma_balance_affido
        from COSTI_&PROVIDER.
        group by esito_finale;
        quit;
    
    
    data RIEPILOGO_&PROVIDER.;
    set RIEPILOGO_&PROVIDER.;
    format somma_balance_affido commax12.2;
    run;
    
   

%MEND;


%COSTI_PROVIDER(TEAM_A);
%COSTI_PROVIDER(TEAM_B);
%COSTI_PROVIDER(TEAM_C);
%COSTI_PROVIDER(TEAM_D);
```

Comment: What do you mean by failing?  Do you mean none of the three conditions tested is true?  You are not asking it to do anything when none of them are true.  That is you do not have a final ELSE.  So if you want it to do something when none of them are true add an additional ELSE DO; ... END; block.

Comment: If you are new to SAS start by creating the SAS code first before trying to learn how to use the macro processor to write the SAS code for you.  What is the IF statement that you want the macro processor to generate?

Comment: Hi Tom, by "failing" I mean exactly what you inferred: none of the three conditions tests true, even when one (or more) should test as such. I don't know if it is something with SAS reading the &i. and &y. macro-variables (for instance, it didn't work on day 10 when I used sysfunc instead of eval/sysevalf) or what else... if you have any hint/clue please share! 

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Write the SAS code you want to run and make sure it works without any macro code.  If you want to see the code your current macro is generating turn on the MPRINT option before calling the macro.  You can then copy out the data step you are having trouble with and run it by itself so you can see why the conditions are not met.  There is nothing really fancy in the IF code you highlighted.  I suspect that the macro variable PROVIDER just does not match any of the values of the variables you are comparing it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro that is generating that IF statement seems to have few issues.

First the macro variable Y is always going to be 0 since it is set to %eval(1-1).  Did you intend Y to always be one less than I?  If so move that %LET statement inside the %DO loop.

Second you keep reading and writing the same dataset over and over.  You should probably move the %DO loop so that it can all be done with one data step.

```
%macro to_worse;
%local i y ;
data COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
  set COSTI_&PROVIDER.;
%do i = 1 %TO &giorno.;
  %let y = %eval(&i.-1);
  if      team_&i. eq ""       and team_&y. eq "&PROVIDER." and balance_&i. = 0 then regolarizzato = "regolarizzato"; 
  else if team_&i. ne team_&y. and team_&y. eq "&PROVIDER." and team_&i. ne "" then to_worse="to_worse";
  else if team_&i. eq team_&y. and team_&y. eq "&PROVIDER." and balance_&y. > balance_&i. then to_better = "to_better"; 
%end;
run;
%mend to_worse;
```

And finally your set of IF/THEN/ELSE conditions do not cover all of the possible combinations of values of TEAM_&I, TEAM_&Y, BALANCE_&I and BALANCE_&Y.  Are you sure that the situations where you think it is not doing what you want are not just the situations that fall into one of those uncovered combinations?

Comment: Thank you! The issue was in fact that Y was always going to be 0 'cause it was set to %eval(1-1). I moved that into the loop and now it's working!